# How can I define operators that implement the algebra of sets?

Tags: operators, algebra, sets

I need to define some operators with properties like idempotence and distribution over union and intersection so that *Mathematica* can symbolically simplify expressions. How do I define such operators?

For example, I want to define $⋃$ and $⋂$ such that

$\qquad (A ⋂ B) ⋃ B = B$

for all $A$ and $B$ and, whenever $A ⊂ B$, then

$\qquad A ⋂ B = A {\rm \ and\ } A⋃ B = B$

Comment: Doesn't Mathematica automatically simplify logic expressions? In this case `Union[Intersection[a,b],b]` should be automatically be simplified to `b` if `a`, `b` are sets. By the way, `=` is the assignment operator, `Set`;  `Equal` is `==`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher Mathematica does not handle Union and Intersection symbolically.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear, how does one implement Union/Intersection etc capability for symbolic sets. I have an idea on how to do this, and would like to provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one idea. Convert the set expression into an equivalent boolean expression, use [`BooleanMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanMinimize) to simplify the boolean expression, and then convert back to a set expression.

**Set expression**

Rather than using [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) and [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection), I will use the built-in symbols [`SquareUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareUnion) and [`SquareIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareIntersection) so that I don't have to modify [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union) and [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection) to work with atomic symbols. So, here are the symbols I will be allowing for set expressions:

- union: [`SquareUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareUnion) ($A \sqcup B$)
- intersection: [`SquareIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareIntersection) ($A \sqcap B$)
- subset: [`SquareSubset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareSubset) ($A \sqsubset B$)
- superset: [`SquareSuperset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SquareSuperset) ($A \sqsupset B$)
- set difference: [`Backslash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Backslash) ($A \backslash B$)
- set complement: [`OverBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OverBar) ($\bar{A}$)
- set equivalence: [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal)
- empty set: `EmptySet` ($\emptyset$)
- universal set: `UniversalSet` ($\mathbb{U}$)

I added the symbols `EmptySet` and `UniversalSet`, similar to how [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals), [`Integers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integers), etc. are handled. I also need to add formatting for these symbols:

```
MakeBoxes[EmptySet, StandardForm] ^= TemplateBox[
    {},
    "EmptySet",
    DisplayFunction -> ("\[EmptySet]"&),
    InterpretationFunction -> ("EmptySet"&)
];
MakeBoxes[UniversalSet, StandardForm] ^= TemplateBox[
    {},
    "UniversalSet",
    DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalU]", FontFamily->"Times"]&),
    InterpretationFunction -> ("UniversalSet"&)
];
```

It is convenient to add some input aliases:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {
    "su" -> "⊔",
    "si" -> "⊓",
    "sb" -> "⊏",
    "sp" -> "⊐",
    "es" -> TemplateBox[
        {},
        "EmptySet",
        DisplayFunction -> ("\[EmptySet]"&),
        InterpretationFunction -> ("EmptySet"&)
    ],
    "us" -> TemplateBox[
        {},
        "UniversalSet",
        DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalU]", FontFamily->"Times"]&),
        InterpretationFunction -> ("UniversalSet"&)
    ]
};
```

**Conversion to Boolean expression**

This part is pretty simple. The Boolean equivalents are:

- union: $A \sqcup B \Longleftrightarrow $`Or[A, B]`
- intersection: $A \sqcap B \Longleftrightarrow$ `And[A, B]`
- subset: $A \sqsubset B \Longleftrightarrow $ `Implies[A, B]`
- superset: $A \sqsupset B \Longleftrightarrow $ `Implies[B, A]`
- set difference: $A\backslash B \Longleftrightarrow $`And[A, Not[B]]`
- set complement: $\bar{A} \Longleftrightarrow $`Not[A]`
- set equivalence: $A = B \Longleftrightarrow $`Equivalent[A, B]`
- empty set: $\emptyset \Longleftrightarrow $`False`
- universal set: $\mathbb{U} \Longleftrightarrow $`True`

So, the following function will convert our set expressions into equivalent Boolean expressions:

```
toBoolean[expr_] := ReplaceAll[
    expr,
    {
        SquareUnion -> Or,
        SquareIntersection -> And,
        SquareSubset -> Implies,
        SquareSuperset -> Reverse @* Implies,
        Backslash -> (And[#1, !#2]&),
        OverBar -> Not,
        Equal -> Equivalent,
        EmptySet -> False,
        UniversalSet -> True
    }
]
```

**Boolean minimization**

The function I will use to "simplify" boolean expressions is [`BooleanMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanMinimize). For a nontrivial example, consider the first set expression in the OP:

```
set = A ⊓ B ⊔ B;
```

The equivalent Boolean expression is:

```
toBoolean[set]
```

> (A && B) || B

Using [`BooleanMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanMinimize) on this expression:

```
BooleanMinimize[toBoolean[set]]
```

> B

as expected.

[`BooleanMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanMinimize) accepts a 2-arg version where the second argument is a condition. We can use this for the second set expression in the OP:

```
set = A ⊓ B;
cond = A ⊏ B;
```

Using [`BooleanMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanMinimize):

```
BooleanMinimize[toBoolean[set], toBoolean[cond]]
```

> A

as expected.

**Conversion back to set expression**

Conversions back to a set expression is basically just the reverse of the conversions from a set expression, except that in some cases, the set expression actually represents a predicate. This means that sometimes False and True should be converted to `EmptySet` and `UniversalSet`, and sometimes (when the set expression represents a predicate) it should be left alone. Also, it would be convenient to convert Boolean expressions representing subset and set difference expressions to the standard set expressions for them.

First, I will define a `setQ` expression that determines whether a set expression represents a set or a predicate:

```
setQ[EmptySet] = True;
setQ[UniversalSet] = True;
setQ[_Symbol] = True;

setQ[(Backslash | SquareUnion | SquareIntersection | OverBar)[a__]] := AllTrue[{a}, setQ]

setQ[_] = False;
```

Examples:

```
setQ[A ⊔ B]
setQ[A ⊏ B]
setQ[A == B]
```

> True

> False

> False

Next, I will define a `fromBoolean` function:

```
fromBoolean[expr_] := ReplaceAll[
    expr,
    {
    Or -> SquareUnion,
    And -> SquareIntersection,
    Not -> OverBar,
    Equivalent -> Equal
    }
]
fromBoolean[a_ && !b_Symbol] := Backslash[a, b]
fromBoolean[!a_Symbol && b_] := Backslash[b, a]
fromBoolean[a_ || !b_Symbol] := SquareSubset[b, a]
fromBoolean[!a_Symbol || b_] := SquareSubset[a, b]
```

**SetSimplify**

Now, we are ready to create a `SetSimplify` function for symbolic sets:

```
Options[SetSimplify] = {Method -> Automatic};

SetSimplify[set_, cond_:True, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{res},
    res = fromBoolean @ BooleanMinimize[
        toBoolean[set],
        toBoolean[cond],
        Method->OptionValue[Method]
    ];
    If[setQ[set],
        res /. {False -> EmptySet, True -> UniversalSet},
        res
    ]
]
```

The OP examples:

```
SetSimplify[(A ⊓ B) ⊔ B]
SetSimplify[A ⊓ B == A, A ⊏ B]
SetSimplify[A ⊔ B == B, A ⊏ B]
```

> B

> True

> True

A few other examples taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets):

*An identity law*

```
set = A ⊓ UniversalSet;
set //TeXForm
```

> $A\sqcap \mathbb{U}$

```
SetSimplify[set]
```

> A

*A complement law*

```
set = A ⊔ OverBar[A];
set //TeXForm
```

> $A\sqcup \bar{A}$

```
SetSimplify[set] //TeXForm
```

> $\mathbb{U}$

*Idempotent laws*

```
SetSimplify[A ⊔ A]
SetSimplify[A ⊓ A]
```

> A

> A

*Absorption laws*

```
SetSimplify[A ⊔ (A ⊓ B)]
SetSimplify[A ⊓ (A ⊔ B)]
```

> A

> A

*One of De Morgan's laws:

```
law = OverBar[A ⊔ B] == OverBar[A] ⊓ OverBar[B];
law //TeXForm
```

> $\overline{A\sqcup B}=\bar{A}\sqcap \bar{B}$

```
SetSimplify[law]
```

> True

*A complement law*

```
set = OverBar[EmptySet];
set //TeXForm
```

> $\overline{\emptyset }$

```
SetSimplify[set] //TeXForm
```

> $\mathbb{U}$

*Reflexivity*

```
SetSimplify[A ⊏ A]
```

> True

*Antisymmetry*

```
SetSimplify[A == B, A ⊏ B && B ⊏ A]
```

> True

*Transitivity*

```
SetSimplify[A ⊏ C, A ⊏ B && B ⊏ C]
```

> True

*Joins*

```
SetSimplify[A ⊏ A ⊔ B]
SetSimplify[A ⊔ B ⊏ C, A ⊏ C && B ⊏ C]
```

> True

> True

*Meets*

```
SetSimplify[A ⊓ B ⊏ A]
SetSimplify[C ⊏ A ⊓ B, C ⊏ A && C ⊏ B]
```

> True

> True

And a few others:

```
SetSimplify[A ⊓ B == A, A ⊔ B == B]
```

> True

```
SetSimplify[A ∖ B, A ⊏ B] //TeXForm
```

> $\emptyset$

```
SetSimplify[A ∖ A] //TeXForm
```

> $\emptyset$

```
set = UniversalSet ∖ A;
set //TeXForm
```

> $\mathbb{U}\backslash A$

```
SetSimplify[set] //TeXForm
```

> $\bar{A}$

Finally, here is everything in one code block:

```
MakeBoxes[EmptySet, form_] ^= TemplateBox[
    {},
    "EmptySet",
    DisplayFunction -> ("\[EmptySet]"&),
    InterpretationFunction -> ("EmptySet"&)
];
MakeBoxes[UniversalSet, form_] ^= TemplateBox[
    {},
    "UniversalSet",
    DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalU]", FontFamily->"Times"]&),
    InterpretationFunction -> ("UniversalSet"&)
];

CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases] = {
    "su" -> "⊔",
    "si" -> "⊓",
    "sb" -> "⊏",
    "sp" -> "⊐",
    "es" -> TemplateBox[
        {},
        "EmptySet",
        DisplayFunction -> ("\[EmptySet]"&),
        InterpretationFunction -> ("EmptySet"&)
    ],
    "us" -> TemplateBox[
        {},
        "UniversalSet",
        DisplayFunction -> (StyleBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalU]", FontFamily->"Times"]&),
        InterpretationFunction -> ("UniversalSet"&)
    ]
};

toBoolean[expr_] := ReplaceAll[
    expr,
    {
        SquareUnion -> Or,
        SquareIntersection -> And,
        SquareSubset -> Implies,
        SquareSuperset -> Reverse @* Implies,
        OverBar -> Not,
        Backslash -> (And[#1, !#2]&),
        Equal -> Equivalent,
        EmptySet -> False,
        UniversalSet -> True
    }
]

setQ[EmptySet] = True;
setQ[UniversalSet] = True;
setQ[_Symbol] = True;

setQ[(Backslash | SquareUnion | SquareIntersection | OverBar)[a__]] := AllTrue[{a}, setQ]

setQ[_] = False;

fromBoolean[expr_] := ReplaceAll[
    expr,
    {
    Or -> SquareUnion,
    And -> SquareIntersection,
    Not -> OverBar,
    Equivalent -> Equal
    }
]
fromBoolean[a_ && !b_Symbol] := Backslash[a, b]
fromBoolean[!a_Symbol && b_] := Backslash[b, a]
fromBoolean[a_ || !b_Symbol] := SquareSubset[b, a]
fromBoolean[!a_Symbol || b_] := SquareSubset[a, b]

Options[SetSimplify] = {Method -> Automatic};

SetSimplify[set_, cond_:True, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{res},
    res = fromBoolean @ BooleanMinimize[
        toBoolean[set],
        toBoolean[cond],
        Method->OptionValue[Method]
    ];
    If[setQ[set],
        res /. {False -> EmptySet, True -> UniversalSet},
        res
    ]
]
```

Comment: Only 3 (now 4) upvotes??! I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, we can build our own `set` framework. (If this is not want you want, I'll delete this post.)

First define a set as an orderless collection of elements.

```
SetAttributes[set, {Flat, Orderless}]

set[args___] := Block[{union},
  union = Union[{args}];
  (
    set @@ union
  ) /; Length[union] != Length[{args}]
]
```

Now define operations on sets... There are more we could define here too

```
set /: Union[s___set] := set[s]
set /: Element[e_, s_set] := MemberQ[s, e]
set /: Subset[s___set] := VectorQ[Partition[Reverse[{s}], 2, 1], SubsetQ @@ # &]
cardinality[s_set] := Length[s]
cardinality[_] = 0;
```

And custom formatting

```
set /: MakeBoxes[s : set[args__], fmt_] := 
  MakeBoxes[Interpretation[〈args〉, s], fmt]

set /: MakeBoxes[set[], fmt_] := MakeBoxes[Interpretation["∅", set[]], fmt]
```

Now test

```
set[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
(* 〈1, 2, 3〉 *)

set[1, 2, 3] ⋃ set[3, 4, 5] ⋃ set[4, 5, 6]
(* 〈1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6〉 *)

set[1, 2, 3] ⋂ set[3, 4, 5]
(* 〈3〉 *)

set[1, 2, 3] ⋂ set[4, 5, 6]
(* ∅ *)

set[1, 2, 3] ⋂ set[3, 4, 5] ⋃ set[4, 8]
(* 〈3, 4, 8〉 *)

5 ∈ set[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(* True *)

set[1, 2, 3] ⊂ set[1, 2, 3, 4] ⊂ set[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(* True *)

cardinality[set[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
(* 5 *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But i want to know that how I can declare that
(A\[Intersecton]B)\[Union] B =B for every A and B.

Where A and B are general sets.