# How to do symbolic logic in Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, logic

I'm currently in Symbolic Logic with homework assignments (not asking for people to do my homework for me) with questions such as the following:

(derive the conclusion using the eighteen rules of inference)

1. R ⊃ B
2. R ⊃ (B ⊃ F )
3. B ⊃ (F ⊃ H )
   Conclusion:  R ⊃ H

Two questions: is there a way to go through the logic, with the rules (if there are built-in symbolic logic rules), to arrive at the specific conclusion (there are always multiple ways to solve it, however)? And more importantly, how do I do symbolic logic in mathematica? I can't find any resources that mention how to do it with the relevance of the kind of symbolic logic I'm doing in my class.

Comment: The superset, ⊃, stands for 'implication' in my class.

Comment: 1. Implies[R,B]
2. Implies[R,Implies[B,F]]
3. Division is not a logical operation.

Comment: Oh, that's the conclusion after the forward slash

Comment: Fixed @RomkeBontekoe

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert on Boolean logic, but this may be some start for you:

```
homework = Implies[r, b] && Implies[r, Implies[b, f]] && Implies[b, Implies[f, h]]
BooleanConvert[homework]
LogicalExpand[homework]
BooleanTable[homework, {r, b, f, h}]
```

You could check [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BooleanComputation.html) and the examples of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of my `SetSimplify` function from my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193513/45431) to [How can I define operators that implement the algebra of sets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101819/45431). After loading the code, we get:

```
SetSimplify[R ⊐ H, R ⊐ B && R ⊐ (B ⊐ F) && B ⊐ (F ⊐ H)]
```

> True

where my code uses `⊐` instead of `⊃`.